# Error deploying Landscape running sudo JUJU_BOOTSTRAP_TO=<hostname> openstack-install

Tags: python, software-center, juju, maas, openstack

We have installed MAAS and have 10 nodes that we want to use for openstack autopilot. We are following this guide https://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud and have all the nodes ready (grey light) and configured IPMI.
But when we run

```
sudo JUJU_BOOTSTRAP_TO=<hostname> openstack-install
```

from the maas server we receive "Error deplyong Landscape." When looking in the log `~/.cloud-install/*.log` I do not find any reason to why the installation fails.

The output from the logfile is the following:

```
[DEBUG: 01-12 11:30:54, utils.py:59] Juju Version: 1.25.6-trusty-amd64
[INFO: 01-12 11:30:54, utils.py:61] Cleanup, saving latest config object.
[INFO: 01-12 11:33:57, openstack-install:227] Starting OpenStack Installer v0.99.28
[INFO: 01-12 11:33:57, openstack-install:228] Start command: ['/usr/bin/openstack-install']
[INFO: 01-12 11:33:57, openstack-install:239] Creating juju directories: /home/megatron/.cloud-install/juju
[INFO: 01-12 11:33:59, openstack-install:295] Running Liberty release
[INFO: 01-12 11:34:13, installbase.py:132] Performing an Autopilot install
[INFO: 01-12 11:34:13, utils.py:780] pollinate: sudo su - -c 'pollinate -q -r --curl-opts "-k --user-agent uoi/5b8ee4ab-9710-42da-8795-c73a73ffb4c7/IL"'
[DEBUG: 01-12 11:34:32, landscape.py:75] Existing MAAS defined, doing a LDS installation with existing MAAS.
[DEBUG: 01-12 11:34:40, utils.py:627] ssh keys exist for this user, they will be used instead.
[DEBUG: 01-12 11:34:40, multi.py:139] Bootstrapping Juju: JUJU_HOME=/home/megatron/.cloud-install/juju juju  bootstrap  --to proper-paper.maas
[ERROR: 01-12 11:48:04, multi.py:218] Failed to get ip directly: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
[DEBUG: 01-12 11:48:07, multi.py:177] Finished MAAS step, now deploying Landscape.
[INFO: 01-12 11:48:22, utils.py:780] pollinate: sudo su - -c 'pollinate -q -r --curl-opts "-k --user-agent uoi/5b8ee4ab-9710-42da-8795-c73a73ffb4c7/ET"'
[ERROR: 01-12 11:48:22, multi.py:384] Problem deploying Landscape: {'output': '', 'err': '2017-01-12 11:48:19 [DEBUG] deployer.cli: Using runtime GoEnvironment on maas\n2017-01-12 11:48:19 [INFO] deployer.cli: Starting deployment of landscape-dense-maas\n2017-01-12 11:48:19 [DEBUG] deployer.import: Getting charms...\n2017-01-12 11:48:19 [DEBUG] deployer.charm: Cache dir /home/megatron/.cloud-install/juju/.deployer-store-cache/cs_trusty_haproxy-16\n2017-01-12 11:48:19 [DEBUG] deployer.charm: Retrieving store charm cs:trusty/haproxy-16\n2017-01-12 11:48:20 [DEBUG] deployer.charm: Cache dir /home/megatron/.cloud-install/juju/.deployer-store-cache/cs_trusty_landscape-server\n2017-01-12 11:48:20 [DEBUG] deployer.charm: Retrieving store charm cs:trusty/landscape-server-15\n2017-01-12 11:48:20 [DEBUG] deployer.charm: Cache dir /home/megatron/.cloud-install/juju/.deployer-store-cache/cs_trusty_postgresql-40\n2017-01-12 11:48:20 [DEBUG] deployer.charm: Retrieving store charm cs:trusty/postgresql-40\n2017-01-12 11:48:21 [DEBUG] deployer.charm: Cache dir /home/megatron/.cloud-install/juju/.deployer-store-cache/cs_trusty_rabbitmq-server-43\n2017-01-12 11:48:21 [DEBUG] deployer.charm: Retrieving store charm cs:trusty/rabbitmq-server-43\n2017-01-12 11:48:21 [DEBUG] deployer.deploy: Resolving configuration\n2017-01-12 11:48:21 [DEBUG] deployer.env: Connecting to environment...\nTraceback (most recent call last):\n  File "/usr/bin/juju-deployer", line 9, in <module>\n    load_entry_point(\'juju-deployer==0.6.4\', \'console_scripts\', \'juju-deployer\')()\n  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/deployer/cli.py", line 135, in main\n    run()\n  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/deployer/cli.py", line 234, in run\n    importer.Importer(env, deployment, options).run()\n  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/deployer/action/importer.py", line 298, in run\n    self.env.connect()\n  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/deployer/env/go.py", line 65, in connect\n    self.client = EnvironmentClient.connect(self.name)\n  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jujuclient.py", line 534, in connect\n    return Connector().run(cls, env_name)\n  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jujuclient.py", line 142, in run\n    cert_path, data.get(\'environ-uuid\'))\n  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jujuclient.py", line 150, in connect_env\n    env = cls(endpoint, name=name, ca_cert=cert_path, env_uuid=env_uuid)\n  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jujuclient.py", line 522, in __init__\n    self.conn = Connector.connect_socket(endpoint, self._ca_cert)\n  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jujuclient.py", line 162, in connect_socket\n    endpoint, origin=endpoint, sslopt=sslopt)\n  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/websocket/_core.py", line 219, in create_connection\n    websock.connect(url, **options)\n  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/websocket/_core.py", line 463, in connect\n    self.sock = ssl.wrap_socket(self.sock, **sslopt)\n  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 487, in wrap_socket\n    ciphers=ciphers)\n  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 243, in __init__\n    self.do_handshake()\n  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 405, in do_handshake\n    self._sslobj.do_handshake()\nssl.SSLError: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:510: error:1409442E:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:tlsv1 alert protocol version\n', 'status': 1}
[ERROR: 01-12 11:48:22, gui.py:269] A fatal error has occurred: Error deploying Landscape.

[ERROR: 01-12 11:48:22, gui.py:270] Error deploying Landscape.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 54, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/controllers/install/multi.py", line 181, in do_install
    self.loop).run()
  File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/controllers/install/multi.py", line 319, in run
    self.deploy_landscape()
  File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/controllers/install/multi.py", line 344, in deploy_landscape
    self.run_deployer()
  File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/controllers/install/multi.py", line 385, in run_deployer
    raise Exception("Error deploying Landscape.")
Exception: Error deploying Landscape.
[DEBUG: 01-12 11:48:22, error.py:35] showing error view for: Error deploying Landscape.
[ERROR: 01-12 12:33:03, ev.py:130] Exception in ev.run():
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/ev.py", line 128, in run
    self.loop.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/main_loop.py", line 278, in run
    self._run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/main_loop.py", line 376, in _run
    self.event_loop.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/main_loop.py", line 1326, in run
    self._loop.run_forever()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/asyncio/base_events.py", line 276, in run_forever
    self._run_once()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1172, in _run_once
    handle._run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/asyncio/events.py", line 120, in _run
    self._callback(*self._args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/raw_display.py", line 393, in <lambda>
    event_loop, callback, self.get_available_raw_input())
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/raw_display.py", line 493, in parse_input
    callback(processed, processed_codes)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/main_loop.py", line 403, in _update
    self.process_input(keys)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/main_loop.py", line 503, in process_input
    k = self._topmost_widget.keypress(self.screen_size, k)
  File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/gui.py", line 136, in keypress
    return super().keypress(size, key)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/container.py", line 1128, in keypress
    return self.body.keypress( (maxcol, remaining), key )
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/decoration.py", line 836, in keypress
    return self._original_widget.keypress((maxcol,), key)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/container.py", line 1587, in keypress
    key = self.focus.keypress(tsize, key)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/decoration.py", line 621, in keypress
    return self._original_widget.keypress(maxvals, key)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/container.py", line 1587, in keypress
    key = self.focus.keypress(tsize, key)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/wimp.py", line 535, in keypress
    self._emit('click')
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/widget.py", line 463, in _emit
    signals.emit_signal(self, name, self, *args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/signals.py", line 264, in emit
    result |= self._call_callback(callback, user_arg, user_args, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/signals.py", line 294, in _call_callback
    return bool(callback(*args_to_pass))
  File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/ui/views/error.py", line 66, in cancel
    raise SystemExit("Install exited because of error.")
SystemExit: Install exited because of error.
[DEBUG: 01-12 12:33:03, utils.py:59] Juju Version: 1.25.6-trusty-amd64
[INFO: 01-12 12:33:03, utils.py:61] Cleanup, saving latest config object.
```

Does anyone have a clue to what the error might be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your reply!

MAAS Version 1.9.4+bzr4592-0ubuntu1 (14.04.1) is the version we are using.

But we did solve this yesterday by reinstalling the maas dns and then it worked on our first attempt.

Answer (score 0):

What distro are you using in MAAS Settings > Deploy ? If it's 14.04 LTS (Trusty) then autopilot fails almost every time. I had to do a manual install.